# development app is deployed on IPhone, but I cannot start it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an app in Xamarin that I want to test on a physical IPhone (normally I test it on Android). I'm connected to a Mac, the development certificate is working and everything is deployed to the point that the app is actually installed on the IPhone itself. The issue however is that when I press the icon to start the app, it tries to start it and then is closes right after that (like it crashes or something).

I'm using Visual Studio for Windows, and it is stated that: "XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start. Verify the Mono Interpreter for  is enabled in the project settings, clean and rebuild the solution.". Mono Interpreter is enabled, I cleaned the solution and rebuild it multiple times. There are no errors given.

The app that is installed now shows the Xamarin icon and Xamarin splash screen (so not the custom one I designed). I don't mind that, but I'm not sure if that has something to do with this.

Does someone know what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Visual Studio for Windows version 17.4.1
iOS version 15.5

Note: this issue is only with the development and deployment directly from Visual Studio from Windows. When the app is distributed to the users (in App Center) the app works as it should.

Comment: You are using Hot Reload right? Can you tell me what you did to connect to the device?  You can check that the Linker is set to "Don't Link" or "Link None".

Comment: In short: I installed iTunes, turned on MacInCloud, started VS for Mac there, connected VS for Windows to this Mac, plugged in the iPhone, used the wizard so it could find it, deployed to the iPhone. Deployment is done and the app is installed, but I cannot start it for some reason. I checked the Linker: it is set to "Don't Link".